# rollover text without <a href>

Tags: html, css

I have a list of links which style I control by CSS. I got a problem with the URL they are going, so I want to control that by javascript. So in my `<a>` i dont want to have `href="link.html'` but if I take that off, the properties that I had with CSS stop working.

```
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #808080;
}
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #808080;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: blue;
}
```

How can I keed that properties only having a `<a>` tag?

Comment: The `:hover` selector should still work to change it blue, but the `:visited` will only work for an actual link (which requires the `href` attribute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just return false on your links. Like:

```
<a href="link.html" onclick="return false;" >​Link</a>​
```

Comment: This is the preferred solution. Then if the client has JavaScript disabled, the links will still work rather than just being worthless text that do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Add `href="#"` what should make the CSS working and that kind of link won't process user into another page.

Comment: In addition to that, put return false when click event is triggered, that's to prevent page from default action of "#" link.